# How to create some notes in DB with the same identification?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have multilanguages in Laravel 5.2 and try to create thee rows in table with the same id for each language.

So, I mean the following:

```
Add article
<form>
   <input type="name" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="1">
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<form>
   <input type="name" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="2">
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>

<form>
   <input type="name" value="">
   <input type="hidden" name="lang" value="3">
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

You can see this is one page with the three similar forms, difference is only in field language.

So, when I submit each of form I need create three rows with the same identification.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a single form:

```
<form>
   <input type="name[1]" value="">
   <input type="name[2]" value="">
   <input type="name[3]" value="">
   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

Then in your controller just add:

```
$names = $request->input('name');
foreach($names as $lang => $name) {
    //Example insert query
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        'name' =>$name, 
        'lang_id' => $lang
    ]);
}
```

This way you can handle adding more languages easily.

Edit: You can use name without an index, but you won't know the language. Those indexes should be the language id or however you're referencing the language. If you want to insert "multiple" rows (3, as you pointed) you need to make multiple inserts.

For multiple fields, not just `name` you can add more `<input>`s the same way:

```
<form>
   <input type="name[1]" value="">
   <input type="name[2]" value="">
   <input type="name[3]" value="">

   <input type="description[1]" value="">
   <input type="description[2]" value="">
   <input type="description[3]" value="">

   <input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
```

And then in your controller:

```
$names = $request->input('name');
$descriptions = $request->input('description');

//If $names and $descriptions rely on the same languages you can do.

foreach($names as $lang => $name) {
    //Example insert query
    DB::table('table')->insert([
        'name' => $name, 
        'description' => $description[$lang]
        'lang_id' => $lang
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Can I use `name[]`? without index?

Comment: I think this is not good solution, because I have a lot fields, not only name[], also it will call DB every time in loop

Comment: Thank you, help me please, how to validtion array `name[]`?

Comment: Take a look at: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: Thank you, but if I have only `name[]` not `'person.*.email' => 'email|unique:users',`

Comment: Then do `'name.*' => 'required',`